# Offset values in cross reference table

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am new to pdf creation and I don't understand an issue with offset values in cross reference table.

This is very basic pdf:

```
%PDF-1.5
1 0 obj <</Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj <</Type /Pages /Kids [3 0 R] /Count 1>>
endobj
3 0 obj<</Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Resources 4 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 500 700] /Contents 6 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj<</Font <</F1 5 0 R>>>>
endobj
5 0 obj<</Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Helvetica>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Length 44>>
stream
BT /F1 24 Tf 100 100 Td (This is test)Tj ET
endstream
endobj
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f
0000000009 00000 n
0000000056 00000 n
0000000111 00000 n
0000000212 00000 n
0000000250 00000 n
0000000317 00000 n
trailer <</Size 7/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
406
%%EOF
```

No matter what values I set in cross reference table PDF is still getting opened without any error.

WHY?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to know why some PDF viewer (you don't name) opens potentially wrong PDFs without complaining? In general PDF viewers try to be quite lax and correct errors without mentioning it. There simply are very many broken PDFs in the wild which the respective producer claims to be correct, and PDF viewers don't want to argue on that with those producers.

Comment: BTW, I just copied your data into an editor, saved it as a PDF, and opened that file in the Adobe Reader. While opening it did not complain, but while closing it asks whether it should save the changes.These "changes" are the afore mentioned corrections done unter the hood.

Comment: mkl every thing is correct in both of your comments!

Comment: Adobe reader just saves the file in a different format...

Comment: Having repaired the original, Adobe Reader uses its preferred way to construct PDFs. But what is your question now?

Comment: now question, but no answer to accept :)

Comment: Ok, I took that as an incentive to make the comments an answer.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

In general PDF viewers try to be quite lax and correct errors without mentioning it. There simply are very many broken PDFs in the wild which the respective producer claims to be correct, and PDF viewers don't want to argue on that with those producers.

BTW, I just copied your data into an editor, saved it as a PDF, and opened that file in the Adobe Reader. While opening it did not complain, but while closing it asks whether it should save the changes. These "changes" are the afore mentioned corrections done unter the hood.

Having repaired the original, Adobe Reader uses its preferred way to construct PDFs, so the document structure may look very different...

If you want to check a PDF file for correctness, you should look for a preflight tool (e.g. the one included with Adobe Acrobat).